# Removing suffix from column names using rename_all?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame with a number of columns in a form var1.mean, var2.mean. I would like to strip the suffix ".mean" from all columns that contain it. I tried using rename_all in conjunction with regex in a pipe but could not come up with a correct syntax. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to use the `dplyr` package, I'd recommend using the `rename_at` function.

```
Dframe <- data.frame(var1.mean = rnorm(10),
                     var2.mean = rnorm(10),
                     var1.sd = runif(10))

library(dplyr)

Dframe %>% 
  rename_at(.vars = vars(ends_with(".mean")),
            .funs = funs(sub("[.]mean$", "", .)))
```

Comment: Inside the rename_at(), ¿Why do you include .vars and .funs?

Comment: those are argument names to `rename_at`.

Comment: `funs` and `rename_at` have been deprecated/superceded.  You should now use `rename_with(~ gsub("[.]mean$", "", .x)`

Answer (score 30):

Using new dplyr:

```
df %>% rename_with(~str_remove(., '.mean'))
```

Comment: I think this also requires the stringr library for str_remove.

Comment: This also needs $ at the end (eg. `".mean$"`) to specify that the patten needs to be matched at the end of the column name (i.e suffix)

Answer (score 10):

We can use `rename_all`

```
df1 %>%
   rename_all(.funs = funs(sub("\\..*", "", names(df1)))) %>%
   head(2)
#        var1        var2       var3       var1       var2       var3
#1 -0.5458808 -0.09411013  0.5266526 -1.3546636 0.08314367  0.5916817
#2  0.5365853 -0.08554095 -1.0736261 -0.9608088 2.78494703 -0.2883407
```

NOTE: If the column names are duplicated, it needs to be made unique with `make.unique`

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25*6), 25, 6, dimnames = list(NULL,
             paste0(paste0("var", 1:3), rep(c(".mean", ".sd"), each = 3)))))
```

Answer (score 9):

You may use `gsub`.

```
colnames(df) <- gsub('.mean','',colnames(df))
```

Answer (score 1):

The below works for me

```
dat <- data.frame(var1.mean = 1, var2.mean = 2)
col_old <- colnames(dat)
col_new <- gsub(pattern = ".mean",replacement = "", x  = col_old)
colnames(dat) <- col_new
```

Comment: Using `pattern = "[.]mean$"` will ensure you only change variable names that end in `.mean`.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this names using `stringi` package `stri_replace_last_regex` function like this:

```
require(stringi)
df <- data.frame(1,2,3,4,5,6)
names(df) <- stri_paste("var",1:6,c(".mean",".sd"))
df
##  var1.mean var2.sd var3.mean var4.sd var5.mean var6.sd
##1         1       2         3       4         5       6
names(df) <- stri_replace_last_regex(names(df),"\\.mean$","")
df
##  var1 var2.sd var3 var4.sd var5 var6.sd
##1    1       2    3       4    5       6
```

The regex is `\\.mean$` because you need to escape dot character (it has special meaning in regex) and also you can add `$` sign at the end to ensure that you replace only names that ENDS with this pattern (if the `.mean` text is in the middle of string then it wan't be replaced).

Answer (score 1):

Lot's of quick answers have been given, the most intuitive, to me would be:

```
Dframe <- data.frame(var1.mean = rnorm(10),        #Create Example
                     var2.mean = rnorm(10),
                     var1.sd = runif(10))
names(Dframe) <- gsub("[.]mean","",names(Dframe))  #remove ".mean"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use stringsplit:

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(16), ncol = 4))
colnames(x) <- c("var1.mean", "var2.mean", "var3.mean", "something.else")

colnames(x) <- strsplit(colnames(x), split = ".mean")
colnames(x)
```